# How to configure iptables rules for connecting 2 eth to the net (forwarding & masquerading)

Tags: iptables, forwarding, masquerade

need some help on configuring iptables rule for forwarding and masquerading

Given I have these configuration:

*switch1* ---- (eth1) ----- *router* ---- (eth2) ----- *switch2*
                                             |
                                             |
                                         (eth0)
                                             |
                                             |
                                      *internet*

where multiple PCs are connected though switch1 and switch2 as well

i'm running this network on a Ubuntu Server where I assume eth1 and eth2 have the same IP address since the default gateway for all the connected PCs is the IP address of this router.

so what i did are :

go to */etc/sysctl.conf* and uncomment the *net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1*

go to */etc/rc.local* and add rules for iptables such as :


*echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE*

and for the router network's interfaces configuration, go to */etc/network/interfaces*
*auto lo

iface lo inet loopback



auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static

address 10.151.74.30

netmask 255.255.255.252

gateway 10.151.74.29



auto eth1

iface eth1 inet static

address 172.16.0.1

netmask 255.255.255.0



auto eth2

iface eth2 inet static

address 172.16.0.1

netmask 255.255.255.0*


So the problem is that all the PCs connected to the router through eth2 can't connect to the internet (tuntap) but all the PCs connected trough the eth1 can do. 

Thus, is there anything I miss on configuring the iptables? Or did I misunderstood?
Help and suggestions are really appreciated. I just started on learning comp networking a month ago, so basically need a guidance here. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: eth1 and eth2 have the same ip?

Comment: yes they have the same ip. 
if the default gateway for the connected PCs is supposed to be the  router's ip, but it has 2 interfaces. aren't they supposed to have the same ip?

Comment: No. You should assign any IP only to one interface. What is the output of `ip a ls` and `ip r ls` ?

Comment: this is the result for ip a ls : bit.ly/YID21W and ip r ls : bit.ly/ZVquih 
so i assumed its a wrong configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You can not have 2 interfaces with the same IP address. Moreover it will not work like that even if you change one interface's IP address to another address in the same network (say 172.16.0.2).

Why do you need 2 interfaces in same network? Do switches *switch1* and *switch2* see each other or are they separated?

If they see each other then there is definitely something wrong with your configuration.

If they don't, you can set up another network on *switch2*, e.g. 172.16.1.0/24, and everything should be fine.

BTW: You don't need `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` if you have `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`.